# Android Studio парсинг какртинки jsoup

Tags: android

Как с помощью библиотеки jsoup загрузить картинку с сайта в елемент ImageView ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью библиотеки jsoup лучше получить ссылку на изображение, а вот загрузить и добавить изображение в ImageView можно с помощью библиотеки [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)